# Add line plots to ggplot2 in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a ggplot2 incrementally, where I add a number of lines to an existing plot like this:

```
pl = ggplot()
pl = pl + somesetup
while(stillhavelines) {
  df = getTheLine(fromsomewhere)
  pl = pl + geom_line(aes(df$x,df$y),linetype=lt,colour=co) ## !!!!
}
ggsave(...)
```

The odd thing is that if I do this then all the line plots will be shown from one single data frame. I instead I try doing this by assigning each dataframe to its own variable it works.

How can I tell ggplot to actually show the lines from the different data frames? Why does it even do this, it is extremely suprising and unintuitive.

Comment: This isn’t really how ggplot2 is used (though it’s possible with a lot of effort I guess). Why not build the *data* incrementally before plotting? For that matter, why build anything incrementally at all?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Because it is good coding practice not to repeat almost identical code over and over. Imagine you want a plot demonstrating how parameters change the pdf of a distribution ([like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Levyskew_distributionPDF.png)) for 4 parameters, 5 values each. You do not care about the coordinates being plotted, so there is no inherent need to build a data frame. Rather than writing 4x5=20 times almost the same `geom_lines` command only varying labels etc (or folding labels, colors, etc into your data frame in a weird way) you might want to use a loop.

Comment: @0range At no point was I suggesting duplicating code. The plot you linked to is trivially doable without repeated code or loops.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Well, if you find this trivial, I am evidently not good enough at working with R and ggplot2. I had this problem the other day (plus having to arrange four of these plots in a cowplot grid, which requires ggplot2). The only way I could make it work was with a combination of a loop and a function.

Comment: @0range Here’s the code for the plot: http://rpubs.com/klmr/levy. For grids you can do the same, adding `facet_grid`; no cowplot necessary.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Alright, thanks for the example. Your function call from inside `ggplot() + scale_color_discrete()` is very neat. [My solution](https://github.com/x0range/FirmLevel-CIEDB/blob/master/distributional_model_visualisations/distributional_model_visualisations.R) was admittedly much less elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the data that's used in a `ggplot` layer with the `data` argument:

```
pl = pl + geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y), linetype = lt, colour = co)
```

If `data` is not specified it will assume that the layer is actually the same each time so it will only show the most recent one.

I tested it with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- list(
  data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 8:12), 
  data.frame(a = 11:15, b = 18:22), 
  data.frame(a = 21:25, b = 28:32)
)

p <- ggplot()

i <- 1

while(i <= length(dat)) {
  df <- dat[[i]]
  p <- p + geom_line(data = df, aes(a, b))  
  i <- i + 1
}

p
```

[image: plot image]

Though as [Konrad Rudolph stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523157/add-line-plots-to-ggplot2-in-a-loop/43523423#comment74099982_43523157) I'm not sure in what scenario you would want to do this. It is better to organize your data first before plotting it for simpler `ggplot` code.